# performSegueWithIdentifier from a NSView subclass?

Tags: swift, segue, nsviewcontroller

I have a document window that contains a number of NSView subclasses, switched between using a tab control. Each of the subclasses, and the window's ViewController, support different user actions accessed through menu items tied to the First Responder.

I'd like to perform a segue from one of those *views* in response to a menu item. However, NSView does not support `performSegueWithIdentifier`, it appears to be something that is part of NSViewController alone.

Can someone suggest a way around this? I have seen suggestions to pass the VC into the views, but I am not clear how to do that. Or perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: Since the `@IBAction`s are connected to First Responder couldn't you capture the action in the view controller and perform the action dependent on the active view.

Comment: Yes, but the action is dependant on information private to the view - specifically the selection in an `NSTableView`. I could expose that but it seems wrong.

Comment: Usually you *control* the workflow from the *control*ler as you have access to the view(s). An alternative is to use the protocol/delegate pattern to send data back to the controller.

Comment: If you want to see why you don't do that in this case, try building a storyboard layout with a dozen views in a tab controller, each one with a custom VC and View. You will conclude, as I did, that any potential pain in bending the object model is **far** less expensive than trying to edit the resulting mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
view.containingController.performSegue()
```

note: you have to add containingController to your views

I WOULD add the viewController to the responder chain and then make containingController a computed property in an extension!

e.g. add vc as responder:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.nextResponder = self.view
    for subview in self.view.subviews {
        subview.nextResponder = self
    }
}
```

e.g. containingController in extension

```
extension NSView {

    var containingController: NSViewController? { 
        get {
            while(self.nextResponder != nil) {
                if(self.nextResponder is NSViewController) {
                    return self.nextResponder
                }                
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note extension written from memory .. there might a mistake or syntax error but you should get the idea

Comment: Note: not actually the way to go. a delegate would be cleaner IMO

Comment: I'm accepting this anyway, because it took seconds to implement and solved the problem. Yes, I know I am abusing the system, but sometimes that is less read-only than doing it "the right way". This is one example.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that (see Daij-Djan's answer), however it is not what I would recommend, since a hypothetical programmer who will be using your code, but is not familiar with it (let's say, you in a year :) ) might be caught by surprise by such behaviour.

I would recommend you to add a delegate (conforming to your custom protocol, let's call it `MyViewDelegate`) to your `NSView` with a method like `viewRequiresToPerformTransition(view: YourViewSubclass)`. Then you implement this method (more generally, you conform to `MyViewDelegate` protocol) in your view controller and inside its implementation perform any segue you want.

Comment: I agree 100% with FreeNickname. Mine is just more fun :D

Comment: Ok I get the idea, but how do I set the delegate in the view? I don't want to do this during the VC's awake, because the views will only be updated when they become visible in the tab view.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz, if your view controller is contained inside a `UITabBarViewController`, you could set the delegate in `viewWillAppear` (of the nested VC), for instance. Or in the part of code responsible for showing the view, if it is initially hidden.

Comment: Well this is all in OSX, but I get what you mean. On it!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz, oh, right, sorry) I mostly do iOS development, so I forgot that the question is about OS X for a moment) Good luck! :)